# calling a web service(ASMX)

Tags: asmx

I am trying to call an ASMX file but I have this error , can you tell me what I did wrong.

[image: the error]

Comment: Is `distance` variable populated or is it empty?

Comment: as I see in your screenshot, distance[0] is `null`, hence the exception